# Need a bidirectional Map which allows duplicate values, and returns list of values given a key

Tags: java, c#, python, data-structures

I have a need for a data structure which I think should be a common need
I need a Map which allows duplicate values(most commonly do, but wait.. getting to the point).. see this sample

```
k1 -> v1
k2 -> v1
k3 -> v1
k4 -> v2
k5 -> v2
```

Now if I do map.getByValue(v1), I should get Set(k1, k2, k3) . Otherwise it should behave like a 'normal' map. It should have high performance, so no for-loop kind of suggestions please.
Also, note that the following will not do for me

```
v1 -> (k1, k2, k3)
v2 -> (k4, k5)
```

.. since I dont want this situation ever (note, k1 is in both lists)..

```
v1 -> (k1, k2, k3)
v2 -> (k4, k5, k1)
```

I don't want to use two map solution. I am thinking of some way to keep values sorted so that getByValue(value) is still performant.

Comment: Why isn't `vi -> (k1, k2, … , kn)` working for you? It seems like your keys are actually values and vice versa. If you override `hashCode` (and `equals`) correctly, a "key" will never be part of multiple lists.

Comment: The two map solution is easy to implement, and gives you O(1) lookup by key and O(1) lookup by value. You could maintain a secondary index that's sorted by value. That would save some space, but it's harder to maintain, and lookup by value would be O(log n). In addition, changing, adding, or deleting a value (that is `map[k] = value`) would be O(log n), as well, whereas with the two-map solution those operations would be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

High performance means that you need some sort of index to search for a key. There are no indexes that work in both directions, so actually you need two of them. So you have to use two multimaps, one for each direction, and a wrapper that will maintain them in consistent state.

Comment: On the other hand Alexey I feel it is possible to avoid two maps if the values are kept sorted (!) That is the challenge.

Comment: If you sort by value, then you can't sort by key (or place values in buckets by key in case of hash tables), so you loose fast search by key. Of course you can have a map key -> pointer_to_a_value and store values in a sorted array. But that's actually two maps, but one is implemented as map (RB-tree, hashmap) and another as sorted vector (which is good for search but bad for insertion).

Comment: Use 1 Map (for key to value) and 1 Multimap (for value to keys), not 2 Multimaps.